# Disable periodic WiFi-Scan in NetworkManager

Tags: wireless, network-manager

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Disabling Network-Manager-Gnome wireless scanning when connected](https://askubuntu.com/questions/230660/disabling-network-manager-gnome-wireless-scanning-when-connected)

I have a problem with the KDE-NetworkManager. I want to stream Pulseaudio via WLAN. Everything works fine, but my problem is that the connection is interrupted every 30 seconds. I found out, that this happens because the NetworkManager (re)scans for available WiFis. I tried to use WICD, but I have problems connecting to my college-network with it.

Has anyone an Idea, how to disable the automatic (re)scan of KDE's network manager?