# Disabling Network-Manager-Gnome wireless scanning when connected

Tags: wireless, 12.10, network-manager

How do I prevent the default Ubuntu Network Manager (`network-manager`) from scanning when connected on my Wi-Fi network?

Comment: The answer to http://askubuntu.com/questions/53498/how-to-change-the-refresh-rate-at-which-the-network-manager-updates-the-wireless applies here.

Comment: that did not help at all.

Comment: why exactly do you want to do this?

Comment: because when it scans, the connection literally lags.

Answer (score 2):

```
killall -STOP NetworkManager
```

works for me in ubuntu 10.04

Answer (score 1):

From: https://blogs.gnome.org/dcbw/2016/05/16/networkmanager-and-wifi-scans/

You can "lock your WiFi connection profile to the BSSID of your access point" by entering your access point's BSSID under "Edit Connections..."

Comment: I am curious how to do this using the nm dbus backend, locking to a specific connection path (which includes the BSSID) used to work, but seems to have reverted back to periodically scanning anyway.  Not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, unless you hack and recompile NetworkManager.