# Ubuntu 20.04 - Disable periodic WiFi Scanning

Tags: network-manager, 20.04, ubuntu-gnome

In reference to this [issue](https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce/issues/143) about the rtl8821ce WiFi chip that faces a lag and packet drops when dealing with periodic WiFi Scan requests, I looked for a way to disable periodic WiFi Scan requests without having to stop NetworkManger. The method of binding the MAC address of the WiFi AP as explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/425617/597726) didn't work for me, the periodic scans continued to occur in background and the problem still exists. Are there other ways of disabling the periodic WiFi scans in Ubuntu 20.04?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you'll need to set the `ap_scan` parameter in wpa_supplicant.  I'm not clear how to customize it using netplan, but as a troubleshooting step you could try running the supplicant in the foreground (something like `wpa_supplicant -Dnl80211 -iwlan0 -c $USER/wpa_supplicant.conf` where you manually create a supplicant config.  Then you can experiment with the ap_scan option as discussed in this other solution: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/490077/skip-scanning-in-wpa-supplicant

Answer (score 0):

This answer worked for me: https://askubuntu.com/a/915214/376429

> From:
> https://blogs.gnome.org/dcbw/2016/05/16/networkmanager-and-wifi-scans/
>
> You can "lock your WiFi connection profile to the BSSID of your access
> point" by entering your access point's BSSID under "Edit
> Connections...